# External table is not in the expected format c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy, oledbconnection

I have seen more answers while googling it, but couldn't solved my problem.
This is the code I have written to insert excel sheet into sql server table.

```
        string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ToString();
        string path = @"D:/Projects/sample.xlsx";
        string excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\";";  

        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
        //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [Name], [City], [Address], [Designation] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
        excelConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dReader;
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
        //Give your Destination table name
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "temp1";
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
        excelConnection.Close();
```

While executing the line "excelConnection.Open();". I am getting an error "External table is not in the expected format."

And "sample.xlsx" is actually an ods format file. I changed its format as xlsx.

What would be wrong in this code. Please suggest me.

Comment: Have you tried to convert ods to xls or xlsx? Or just renamed?

Comment: You need to open that excel and save it as .xlsx

Comment: I think the file is in another format which excel import could not read. You can convert the file using excel or online tools and then try to import.

Comment: @Jenish: Yes. I have saved it as .xls file and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the conversation in the comments, you have to convert the `ODS` file into `XLS` or `XLSX` format not just renaming it. You can use `Excel` or `Online tools` to convert `ODS` files.